# Opening a Calculator in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, calculator, implicit

I'm looking to open a calculator from within my Activity.  Here's my code right now and it works:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.android.calculator2",
"com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
```

I would like to make this an implicit call because I don't know what calculator the use would like to use and I would like to leave the option open to receive a value from the calculator, which the android one apparently doesn't do.  I haven't been able to find a good example of how to implicitly ask for a type of application.

I've looked at http://www.openintents.org/en/intentstable but I guess I don't completely understand how to use that site.

I think I understand the intent of intents, but maybe I just don't have a firm grasp on how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is probably the best you can do. I just checked the AndroidManifest.xml for `com.android.calculator2.Calculator` and it doesn't listen for any other intents.