# Addition using calculator

Tags: android, android-intent, calculator

I have a requirement such that I need to add two integers using built in calculator. Here I need to pass values to that implicit intent android add these values and should show the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6364188/79061), it would appear that the built-in calculator app does not accept any intent that would allow you to pass it data.