# How to add android default application to custom app

Tags: android

I developed an application for Android tablet using Android 3.1.Now I want to add default application (ex:Calculator) which is come with tablet to my application and its own icon also.
is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364136/opening-a-caclulator-in-android

Comment: What have you tried? Stack overflow isn't for you to post a request and get source code. Try the link above. Seems to have all the code you need.